# undefined reference to "functionName" with shared files

Tags: c, gcc

This is my makefile:

```
gcc -c -fPIC ./command/cd.c -o ./command/cd.o
gcc -c -fPIC ./command/exit.c -o ./command/exit.o
gcc -c -fPIC ./command/pwd.c -o ./command/pwd.o
gcc -shared ./command/*.o -o ./commands.o

gcc -fPIC -c -o utils/command.o utils/command.c
gcc -fPIC -c -o utils/lineParser.o utils/lineParser.c
gcc -fPIC -c -o utils/memory.o utils/memory.c
gcc -fPIC -c -o utils/printing.o utils/printing.c
gcc -shared ./utils/*.o -o ./utils.o

gcc -c -fPIC ./runner.c -o ./runner.o
gcc -shared utils.o commands.o runner.o -o app.o -lreadline

gcc app.o -o slash
```

I don't understand why I'm getting :

```
app.o: undefined reference to `Malloc'
app.o: undefined reference to `exitCommandRunner' 
app.o: undefined reference to `pwdCommandRunner'
[...]
```

- `Malloc`
  --> defined in `utils/memory.h`
  --> implemented in `utils/memory.c`
- `exitCommandRunner`
  --> is defined in `command/exit.h`
  --> implemented in `command/exit.c`
- `pwdCommandRunner`
  --> is defined in `command/pwd.h`
  -->implemented in `command/pwd.c`

I don't understand since I'm including them in `runner.c` :

```c
#include "runner.h"
#include "./utils/memory.h"
#include "./utils/command.h"
#include "./utils/lineParser.h"
#include "./utils/printing.h"
#include "./command/cd.h"
#include "./command/pwd.h"
#include "./command/exit.h"
```

Did I minsunderstood something ?

Comment: You're most likely missing `memory. exit.o pwd.o` in `gcc -shared utils.o commands.o runner.o -o app.o -lreadline`

Comment: they're all included in ``gcc -shared ./utils/*.o -o ./utils.o`` and ``gcc -shared ./command/*.o -o ./commands.o``

Comment: Check if they're actually in `commands.o` with `nm commands.o`

Comment: Seems that yes ?
``0000000000000e54 T exitCommandRunner`` and ``0000000000000fda T pwdCommandRunner``

Comment: You are creating shared libraries with misleading names.  I recommend using prefix `lib` for your libraries, and I *strongly* recommend using extension `.so`.  Example: `libcommands.so`.  Naming your libraries with suffix `.o` gives entirely the wrong idea about what they are.  However, this is for your benefit and ours, not GCC's.  GCC will recognize what type of file it is from its content.

Comment: Are you sure you actually want shared libraries and the dynamic linking that comes with them?  It's your choice, but I'm dubious.  There's no particular reason why you couldn't build static libraries containing PIC objects, and link them statically.

Comment: But the actual problem is likely to be the order of the arguments to your link command.  It matters.  Generally speaking, the linker will resolve symbol references in object files only against symbols exposed by the same or other object files or by libraries that appear later on the command line.

Comment: You mean doing something like that : ``gcc ./utils/*.c ./command/*.c ./runner.c -o runner -lreadlin`` ? I just find it a bit meh- to compile everything in one command

Comment: No, I said no such thing.  Perhaps we need to take a step back: do you understand that there is a difference between object files and libraries, and that libraries come in "static" and "shared" flavors, which are quite different?

Comment: To be honest ? Absolutely not, I wasn't trained for that at all. And I thought that I had the good order in my link commands, I really don't ee where it can be wrong.

Comment: Ok.  Evidently, you also don't realize that what you're calling a makefile isn't one.  It appears to be a shell a script.  That's ok, but `make` has features that might help you manage building a project with multiple source files spread across multiple directories.

Comment: Oh no no- About that, I just showed the command that are executed by the make file ! 
I didn't paste the makefile itself because it is pretty long

Comment: Either way, the simplest thing to do would be to compile each .c file to an object file, and then link all the object files together into an executable, all at once, skipping intermediate aggregates such as `commands.o` and `app.o`.

Comment: Indeed, it worked, but why this intermediate files would cause a problem ?

Comment: It's the order of objects to link. Libraries are searched for unresolved symbols, but as your app.o comes last, its references are not yet encountered as the linker processes the libraries. There are for sure several duplicates here on SO, but I'm too short of time to look them up.